# How to convert HTML to PDF in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a HTML form data getting from database. 
I use PHP framework codeigniter . we want generate a PDF file from this HTML form data. tell me how to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: *tell me how to do*: research sample and tutorial online, select some, understand them, create your own code, and if this doesn't work, post the relevant part of your code here. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna look at html2Pdf. It is a php class based on FPDF and it allows you to create PDF file from HTML. So just format your text using html and then create its pdf. Its very flexible and give greate control.

[SorceForge Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/)

Or You can also look at this: [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Look at DomPDF https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
Examples: http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php

By the way, on my project I use Zend Framework and ZendParadoxPDF to ge generate pdf. But it requires Java, so ASAP I'll redevelop it using DomPDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mPDF Library to create pdf in codeignator. create the mpdf.php file. After that put it into the CodeIgniter library directory.

copy this code to mpdf.php

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

class M_pdf {

 public $param;
 public $pdf;
 public function __construct($param = "'c', 'A4-L'")
 {
    $this->param =$param;
    $this->pdf = new mPDF($this->param);
 }
}
```

Then, download mPDF Library from github or  mpdf website.After downloading, Extract it and put the mpdf folder into CodeIgniter third_party directory.Then, 
Open your controller(here,i am using Welcome controller) ,create a method on that controller as following

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
 function my_mPDF(){

$filename = time()."_order.pdf";

$html = $this->load->view('unpaid_voucher',$data,true);

// unpaid_voucher is unpaid_voucher.php file in view directory and $data variable has infor mation that you want to render on view.

$this->load->library('M_pdf');

$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

//download it D save F.

$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output("./uploads/".$filename, "F");
}
}
?>
```

Here, my_ mPDF function of Welcome controller will generate pdf file of common/template view file.

It’s done. I hope it will help you.